# Create multiple instances of class & store them in vector<class>

Tags: c++, vector, instance

What I'm trying to do is create multiple instances of a class `Point` and access the class variables for each instance.

```
class Point
{
public:
    float x, y, z;
};
```

In the following main() program, I'm creating a single instance of type `Point`, called point_ and pushing the same instance multiple times in the vector.

```
int main() 
{

    std::vector < Point > vect;
    Point point_;

    int num_instances; // is user defined

    for (int i = 0; i < num_instances; i++)
    {
        vect.push_back(point_); // (^^^)
    }
}
```

(^^^) Here, the **problem** is this vector of type `Poin`t is adding 1 single instance (called point_) that I manually created. **What I want** is that based on num_instances input from user (say 5), the same number (i.e. 5) of instances of type `Point` should get created and stored in this vector (called vect).

Comment: What? `push_back` *copies* your variable `point_`, so it already creating a vector of `num_instances` number of `Point`. You could change one element of this vector, and all the other elements would be unchanged. Again, they are separate `Point` instances, that were copied from `point_`

Comment: Uh no. You are adding a _copy_ of `point_` each time you call `push_back`.

Comment: The `vector<>::push_back()` function takes a copy of your instance, the copies won't reference the originally created `point_` anymore.

Comment: You're already making multiple instances, plus you could just do `std::vector < Point > vect(Point());`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ are you sure? it's the same `Point` type instance though.

Comment: @Daqs No it isn't, it's a *copy* of that instance. You are **not** using references or pointers, so these are different objects

Comment: So you need to create new vector for each loop iteration.  Use  new vector<point> into the push_back function in order to allocate new memory for each instance

Comment: Yes, we're _absolutely_ positive the code in your post is adding a copy of `point_` to the vector.

Comment: @Daqs Yes, [I'm a 100% sure](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the program already does precisely what you want it to do. There's no question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In the following main() program, I'm creating a single instance of type Point, called point_ and pushing the same instance multiple times in the vector.

Yes you are creating a single instance of type `Point` called `point_`. No you are not pushing the same instance multiple times in the vector.

If you were pushing the same instance into the vector multiple times, it would mean that the instance is in multiple places at once. This cannot happen. I'll use an analogy of a physical paper document. If you wanted to put this document into a pile of documents multiple times, you would have to make copies of it. Same goes for your `Point` object.

When you call `push_back` on the vector, it allocates memory for a `Point` and copies the given `Point` object into that memory. Since it will allocate completely separate chunks of memory for each item in the vector, there is no way they can be the same object.

**Edit:** here's proof: http://ideone.com/F5XX4u

Answer (score 2):

The push_back method makes a copy of the item you push in. To prove this, when you run the follow code

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "math.h"
#include <vector>

class Point
{
    public:
    float x, y, z;
};

int main()
{

    std::vector < Point > vect;
    Point point_;
    int num_instances = 5; // is user defined

    for (int i = 0; i < num_instances; i++)
    {
        vect.push_back(point_); // (^^^)
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_instances; i++){
      printf(" %d: %x\n", i, &(vect[i]) );
    }
}
```

You get the following output:

```
0: fbd00060
1: fbd0006c
2: fbd00078
3: fbd00084
4: fbd00090
```

This means that each object in the vector is an instance of a different Point object. If they were the same instance, then they would all have the same address

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back), which does the following:

> Appends the given element value to the end of the container.
>
> 1) The new element is initialized as a copy of value.
>
> 2) value is moved into the new element.

you could use [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back), which constructs a whole new object from the parameters and appends it to the vector.

You can use it like this:

```
int main() 
{

    std::vector < Point > vect;

    int num_instances; // is user defined

    for (int i = 0; i < num_instances; i++)
    {
        // You should use the values you want here
        float x = 0.0f;
        float y = 0.0f;
        float z = 0.0f;
        vect.emplace_back(x, y, z);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use push_back, then the  x, y, z values of the copied instances stored in vector would still be different, right?